# Reverse the order on an index for a ClientDataSet

Tags: delphi, indexing, tclientdataset

I'm wanting to reverse the order of an index in a TClientDataSet, the following code looks like it should do the trick but does nothing.  Is there a nice way to reverse the order of an index?

```
procedure TForm8.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  index: TIndexDef;
begin
  index := ClientDataSet1.IndexDefs.Find('LengthIndex');
  if ixDescending in index.Options then
    index.Options := index.Options - [ixDescending]
  else
    index.Options := index.Options + [ixDescending];
end;
```

Comment: Why not delete the index and create it again? There should be no faster way to do it, because (CMIIW) if there would be a way to very quickly reverse an index, there would be no reason to have the distinction between ascending and descending indices - the database engine could order on the fly then (based on the query).

Comment: Maybe you will have a look at http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/29056 Not only a long explanation on CDS Index but also some code that fits your needs - i think so :o)

Answer (score 9):

`TIndexDef.Options` are used when creating the indexes. They can't be used to try and affect an existing index. See the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Data.DB.TIndexDef.Options) (**emphasis** mine):

> **When creating a new index**, use Options to specify the attributes of the index. Options can contain zero or more of the TIndexOption constants ixPrimary, ixUnique, ixDescending, ixCaseInsensitive, and ixExpression.
>
> **When inspecting the definitions of existing indexes, read Options** to determine the option(s) used to create the index.

You'll need to create a separate index with the `ixDescending` value set. You can then switch back and forth by just changing the `IndexName` property.

Comment: +1, the proper way is create two indexes and switch between them using the `IndexName` property.

Comment: What does (emphasis mine) mean?

Comment: @CapeCodGunny: It means I'm the one who added the **bold** to it to emphasis those points.

Comment: Okay, got it. So, you lifted parts of the documentation and bolded those points that drive home the concept. That's pretty good. Thanks.

Comment: Great algo suggestion `You'll need to create a separate index with the ixDescending value set. You can then switch back and forth by just changing the IndexName property.` Simple, elegant, and very useful to me!

Answer (score 1):

This is the method I ended up settling on for sorting in both directions.  Basically it just creates and frees indexes, not very pretty but works.  This is much easier to do with a [TFDMemTable](https://youtu.be/ohJfGDF__MQ) (if you have access to FireDAC)

```
type
  TSortByFieldOption = (ForceAscending, ForceDescending);
  TSortByFieldOptions = set of TSortByFieldOption;

procedure SortClientDataSetByField(cds : TClientDataSet; FieldName : String; Options : TSortByFieldOptions = []);
const
  IndexName = 'GridSort';
var
  i: integer;
  index: TIndexDef;
  OldOrder: string;
  IndexOptions : TIndexOptions;
begin
  cds.DisableControls;
  try
    i := cds.IndexDefs.IndexOf(IndexName);
    if i <> - 1  then
    begin
      index := cds.IndexDefs.Find(IndexName);
      OldOrder := index.Fields;
      try
        cds.DeleteIndex(IndexName);
      except;
        OutputDebugString('no index?');
        //there seem to be conditions where the index does not exist but
      end;
      index.Free; //delete index for some reason does not free the index
      indexOptions := index.Options;
    end else
      IndexOptions := [ixDescending];

    index := cds.IndexDefs.AddIndexDef;
    index.Name := IndexName;
    index.Fields := FieldName;
    if ForceAscending in Options then
      index.Options := []
    else if ForceDescending in Options then
      index.Options := [ixDescending]
    else if OldOrder = FieldName  then
    begin
      if (IndexOptions = [ixDescending]) then
        index.Options := []
      else
        index.Options := [ixDescending];
    end;
    cds.IndexName := IndexName;
  finally
    cds.EnableControls;
  end;
end;
```