# Delphi ClientDataSet Sorting by changing IndexName

Tags: sql, delphi, sorting, tclientdataset, tdbgrid

I've been learning about the ClientDataSet in delphi and how it can help sort my SQL database. The data is showing fine in my TDBGrid and i've enabled sorting by clicking on a header by changing the IndexField of the ClientDataset. I want to make it go descending on sorts sometimes though so have been trying to use 2 IndexNames outlined here https://stackoverflow.com/a/13130816/4075632

However, when I swap the IndexName  from DEFAULT_ORDER to CHANGEINDEX, all data in my DBGrid disappears. I'm pretty new to all of this, and I know it will depend on my situation, but what are some of the ways this happens and I will try to troubleshoot them.

I have 1 TSQLConnection connected to TSQLQuery, and that connected to TDataSetProvider, and that connected to my ClientDataSet which leads to a TDataSource to the TDBGrid. Why might the ClientDataSet which is usually fine cause problems when I change its name? Please bear in mind that most of the settings are default because I'm not too sure about these components. Thanks, I hope you can provide some useful help and I'm sorry it may be difficult to se my situation.

Toby

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use the following code to build indexes for a clientdataset:

```
Procedure BuildIndices (cds: TClientDataSet);
var
 i, j: integer;
 alist: tstrings;

begin
 with cds do
  begin
   open;
   logchanges:= false;
   for i:= 0 to FieldCount - 1 do
    if fields[i].fieldkind <> fkCalculated then
     begin
      j:= i * 2;
      addindex ('idx' + inttostr (j), fieldlist.strings[i], [], '', '',  0);
      addindex ('idx' + inttostr (j+1), fieldlist.strings[i], [ixDescending], '', '', 0);
     end;
   alist:= tstringlist.create;
   getindexnames (alist);
   alist.free;
   close;
  end;
end;
```

As a result, there is an index 'idx0' for sorting column 0 ascending and 'idx1' for sorting column 0 descending; 'idx2' and 'idx3' for column 1, etc.

Then, in the grid's OnTitleClick event, I have the following

```
procedure Txxx.DBGrid1TitleClick(Column: TColumn);
var
 n, ex: word;

begin
 n:= column.Index;
 try
  dbgrid1.columns[prevcol].title.font.color:= clNavy
 except
 end;

 dbgrid1.columns[n].title.font.color:= clRed;
 prevcol:= n;
 directions[n]:= not directions[n];
 ex:= n * 2;
 if directions[n] then inc (ex);
 with clientdataset do
  try
   disablecontrols;
   indexname:= 'idx' + inttostr (ex);
  finally
   first;
   enablecontrols
  end;
end;
```

In each form, I define an array of booleans ('directions'), one element per grid column. These elements track whether a column should be sorted ascending or descending.

Comment: Thank you! Nearly there, but what is prevcoI? Im getting undeclared variable errors. Thanks

Comment: @TobyFox: prevcol is an integer variable belonging to the form (forgot about that). It stores the value of the previous selected column.

Comment: Hi thanks. I'm sure this will work because it seems right, but my database table is still not showing and every time I click on a heading I get error "cannot perform action on closed dataset". So i suppose my original problem still stands. Data isnt being shown in the DBGrid when the name of the CDS is anything other than the default. What thinks should I check? Thanks so much, Toby

Comment: Ok I now know it breaks after this line:  
`with CustomerCDS do
  try
   disablecontrols;
   IndexName:= 'idx' + inttostr (AscDescSetBegin);
   showmessage('First Part');
  finally
   first;`

What is it with "first" that causes that message? Thanks

Comment: @TobyFox: Judging by your comments, the dataset is closed - you should open it after the 'buildindices' procedure in order to display the data, or possibly remove the 'close' line from 'buildindices'. 'First' causes the dataset to be displayed from the first record in the new sorting order.

Comment: Thank you so much! That works absolutely perfectly. I really appreciate that!

Comment: Excellent solution!  But can you explain the purpose of this:   alist:= tstringlist.create;   getindexnames (alist);   alist.free;  And what is "getindexnames". THANK YOU!

Comment: @KevinKillion: GetIndexNames retrieves a list of available indexes defined for the table. It's been several years since I wrote that code (a few years before I posted it here) and I don't recall exactly why I added those three lines. I suspect that they make the index names 'visible'. Try without those three lines and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

The ClientDataSet comes with two predefined indexes: DEFAULT_ORDER and CHANGEINDEX, which are of no real use for your task, because you cannot tweak them to your needs. So you have to create your own indexes. A comprehensive description by Cary Jensen can be found in [this article](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/29056) as well as in his highly recommended [book about ClientDataSets](http://www.jensendatasystems.com/cdsbook/).